# Type conversion in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF and am finding a surprisingly scarce amount of information regarding what I thought was a basic problem, which is to use an integer for the text in a TextBlock. Here is how I defined my resources in `app.xaml`:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and

```
<Application.Resources>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="MyResourceName">-1</sys:Int32>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is correctly defined and functional because VS locates in when I try to use it in a simple TextBlock object:

```
<TextBlock Name="MyTextboxName" Text="{DynamicResource MyResourceName}" />
```

The problem is that it generates an error explaining, of course, that it can't convert an integer to a string by default. Normally, I would cast it before I knew I was typing, but I don't know how to cast in xaml. I considered binding, but it doesn't seem to be focused around user-defined variables as much and would be more cumbersome, so then I looked at converters. I also found little about converting integers to strings in xaml. If there isn't a solution, I can simply make the variables strings and convert them to integers or floats only for conversions, then convert them back, but that would be a major (and messy) pain.

Edit: To be clear, I'm really asking two questions:

1. Is type conversion possible in only Xaml?
2. Is there a default converter for converting one primitive type to another?

Comment: Ok, how about using a Label instead, and set its `Content` property? You would also be able to set its `ContentStringFormat` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already is in the Framework a TypeConverter that converts an int to a string, the issue here is that it is not applied when you are using the `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`.

You just have to bind to your resource:

```
<TextBlock Name="MyTextboxName" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyResourceName}}" />
```

You cannot use DynamicResource though.

Comment: That gives me an error about needing a path specified. I couldn't find anything at all where the path wasn't an Xaml element, so I don't know how binding would work on a resource.

Comment: You don't need a Path for binding, you bind directly to Source. From MSDN: "To bind to an entire object, you do not need to specify the Path property."

Comment: I read more about binding to find out when I could use markup extensions (like the way you have two of them together) and I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a converter and use that to convert for you. You then add it as a resource.

[TypeConverters and XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It just seemed like such a primitive conversion as int to string should have an existing converter. I decided to write one (stored in a separate .cs file). Visual Studio can find the class, but I can't access any methods within it. The class inherits and implements from IValueConverter. Are there any special things I might be missing that make it "visible" to the Xaml?